# How to move column from referenced table to referrer table using only SQLite language dialect?

Tags: sqlite

I have following table structure in SQLite database:

```
    CREATE TABLE A (id integer primary key, name text, room Integer);
    CREATE TABLE B (id integer primary key, idA integer not null, code blob, FOREIGN KEY(idA) REFERENCES A(id));
```

For each record in A there are 1 to n records in B that refers it. Desired table structure is:

```
    CREATE TABLE A (id integer primary key, name text);
    CREATE TABLE B (id integer primary key, idA integer not null, code blob, room Integer, FOREIGN KEY(idA) REFERENCES A(id));
```

So, I would like to transer room column from A to B without data loss: recreate table A without room column, delete duplicates from A, add room column to B, set it depends on what values were in referenced A records room columns (original A table) and reassign idA for B records.

Is it possible using only SQLite and if it is, how to do this, using only SQLite?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e26e2/1 .

creating the databases :

```
CREATE TABLE A (id integer primary key, name text, room Integer);
CREATE TABLE B (id integer primary key, idA integer not null, code blob, FOREIGN KEY(idA) REFERENCES A(id));
```

Fill in some test data :

```
insert into A (id, name, room) values (1, "azerty", 123) ;
insert into A (id, name, room) values (2, "querty", 456) ;

insert into B (id, idA, code) values (10, 1, "code 1") ;
insert into B (id, idA, code) values (15, 1, "code 1b") ;
insert into B (id, idA, code) values (20, 1, "code 1c") ;
insert into B (id, idA, code) values (25, 2, "code 2") ;
insert into B (id, idA, code) values (30, 3, "code 3") ;
```

copy the wrong table layouts to tables we will later drop :

```
alter table B rename to old_B ;
alter table A rename to old_A ;
```

Create tables according the correct layout :

```
CREATE TABLE A (id integer primary key, name text);
CREATE TABLE B (id integer primary key, idA integer not null, code blob, room Integer, FOREIGN KEY(idA) REFERENCES A(id));
```

Copy selected data from old_A into A :

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO A ( id, name)
SELECT id, name FROM old_A ;
```

fill B with an inner join to "line up" room with correct idA :

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO B ( id, idA, code, room)
SELECT old_B.*, old_A.room FROM old_B INNER JOIN old_A ON old_B.idA = old_A.id  ;
```

drop the old tables

```
DROP TABLE old_A ;
DROP TABLE old_B ;
```

Comment: Thank you, but seems I wasn't enough accurate with question. Main problem is that after moving "room" column there would be duplicates with same "name" column value in A table. And main problem is in normalization to 3NF (old A table should have unique constraint at name and room, after moving name column, in new A table name is unique). In my case for A records (1, "Mozzy", 123) and (2, "Mozzy", 12) after executing your statements would be two Mozzy, but should be one and all B records that refers to old Mozzy with id 1 and id 2 should refer only to one new Mozzy.

Comment: I mean, something like this, but for SQLite: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1497663